# VsCode - Python: Create Environment not available

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

The question is about [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

The section [Using the Create Environment command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command) of the above link reads:

> In Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), start typing the **Python: Create Environment** command to search, and then select the command.

But when I type the above command in VsCode, as shown below, it says: `No matching commands`.

[image]

What I may be missing, and how we can fix the issue?

I have version 1.65.2 of `VsCode`, and version 3.10 of `python` installed on the latest version of `Windows 10 Pro`

Comment: Do you have any of the Python extensions installed?

Comment: @TimRoberts The only python extension installed is from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python). In `VsCode` it reads: **Python extension for Visual Studio Code**: A Visual Studio Code extension with rich support for the Python language (for all actively supported versions of the language: >=3.7), including features such as IntelliSense (Pylance), linting, debugging, code navigation, code formatting, refactoring, variable explorer, test explorer, and more!

Comment: So, you have not installed the "Python Environment Manager" extension?  I believe that's what supplies these commands.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, I've not. But the document I linked, in the post above, does not mention `Python Environment Manager` as a requirement.

Comment: Then you should file a documentation bug.  Complete Python support is not inherent to VSCode.  The languages are all extensions.

Comment: @TimRoberts Good advice. Bug submitted [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21280).

Answer (score 0):

> I have version 1.65.2 of VsCode

You are using an old version of VSCode.

Please update [VSCode to 1.78.2](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_78) and Python extension.

Otherwise, please try [creating a virtual environment in the terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment-in-the-terminal).

**Venv**

```
# macOS/Linux
# You may need to run `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` first on Debian-based OSs
python3 -m venv .venv

# Windows
# You can also use `py -3 -m venv .venv`
python -m venv .venv
```

**Conda**

```
conda create -n env-01 python=3.9 scipy=0.15.0 numpy
```

Comment: It helps to use a makefile as well when on linux. That way you can automatically enter your venv when running code. It also can be used to automatically reinstall all dependencies when the `requirements.txt` changes. It's very helpful when working with a venv.